Bash: $'\377\376export': command not found error on terminal startup
Every time I open the terminal, I get the following error message:
bash: $'\377\376export': command not found
This message appears before the terminal is fully loaded and ready for input. While it doesn't seem to affect the functionality of the terminal, and I can work regularly after the message appears, it's still an annoyance.
This issue occurs on every new project I open and only on one particular computer. On another computer where I've cloned the same project, the issue does not occur. 
I've tried researching this issue, but I couldn't find a clear solution. Does anyone know what might be causing this error message and how to resolve it?
Some additional information:
Operating System: windows10
Shell: Bash
Terminal: VS Code terminal
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to get rid of this error message on terminal startup.
I have no idea what even to try

Is that export the very first line of the file it's in?

Which File are you referring to?

Literal meaning: One of the commands which you have (carefully?) crafted into your bash startup files, does not exist in your PATH.
From the octal codes in the error message, I would infer that you you have a BOM at at the start of the file, so check your startup files for a BOM.
If you are lazy, create a new subshell with bash -lx. The trace should tell you, in which startup file the problem happens, so you don't have to look through all of them.

bash -lx! Excellent!

Can you please simplify your answer? I'm still stuck. Everything you wrote above is really strange to me. I tried going to .bashrc and deleting the EXPORT word as suggested, but it's still not working.

I didn't say you should delete the word export - this is fine -, but to check that you perhaps have a BOM. I would do a xxd ~/.bashrc | head -n 1 or a head -c 2 | xxd to see what's going on. And I would post a link to the trace you get from bash -lx, as I suggested.
